# The bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor', defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/MethodSecurityConfig.class], could not be registered

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, activiti

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor', defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/MethodSecurityConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I use the SpringBoot 2.2.12 and SpringSecurity 5.2.8 and activiti 7.1.0.M4 then get the error.

I think it may coursed by activiti conflict with SpringSecurity.

Comment: and you expect us to solve this without you showing us your code? if you expect any help, then put some effort into your question, what have you tried, have you debugged your code, what does your code look like. How is it reproducible. voted to close

Answer (score 0):

I think. If there is a conflict between the two framework bean naming definitions.You can try to customize one of them

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My Technical Manager have solved the problem. The two framework have a same annotation  configuration, so it conflict.

Comment: what is the solution ?